# How do I make an object fly and rotate on it's (Local) Z axis with keyframes?

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I have an arrow that I'm animating across my scene. I want the arrow to be rotating as it's flying but, since I don't have the arrow flying exactly on one of the axises, I'd have to animate it along it's local Z axis. But every time I try to do this, it doesn't animate properly because of the way blender reads animation on the 3D axises.
My question is, **Is there any way to animate the object rotating on the local Z axis while it flys across the scene?**
P.S. Sorry, this is kind of a generic question, so I'd be happy to provide any extra info.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is animate an empty with the large scale motion, like so :

[image]

Parent your "Arrow" to the empty.

[image]

Animate the "Arrow", in this case I keyframed 1500° of Z axis rotation.

[image]

Comment: Great Hack! Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 1):

i would use a curve to move the arrow.

Then give the arrow a follow path constraint:

[image]

And then animate the rotation easily by giving two keyframes on the forward axis:

[image]

[image]